# flex box align-items example from Mozilla not working

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

this code is from Mozilla which is to make div in centre but it makes only centre horizontally

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: I have tried in few different browser it doesn't work for me

Comment: because the doc show only the relevant part of the code ....

Answer (score 2):

Works perfectly fine. Give the container some height to see the effect:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height:200px;
}

.box div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know it works when you give height with pixel but I want in 100% or without height as its done in example which doesn't work

Comment: @Punya inspect the element and you will see . the Doc don't give FULL code, they give the relevant code, they will not show the height they ADDED

Answer (score 0):

No problem with your code. You have to give `height` to the `flex-container`

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height:300px;
  background-color:#4a4545;
}

.box div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:#C58B8C;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

These reason is that you have not given any attributes to the `<div>` which is inside of the `<div class="box">`
Please check the codes I've submitted I've done exactly like it is no the Mozilla site.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* add the lines below */
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px dotted rgb(96, 139, 168)
}

.box div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  /* add the lines below */
  border: 2px solid rgb(96, 139, 168);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(96, 139, 168, .2);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parent `div` (`.box`) must have a width and height, `%` or pixels. Try first to set the pixels.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="box">
</div>
 <style>
body {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; 
  height:90%;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
</style>
<!--   
 ______   ______   ______   __       
/_____/\ /_____/\ /_____/\ /__/\     
\::::_\/_\:::_ \ \\:::_ \ \\.:\ \    
 \:\/___/\\:\ \ \ \\:\ \ \ \\::\ \   
  \:::._\/ \:\ \ \ \\:\ \ \ \\__\/_  
   \:\ \    \:\_\ \ \\:\_\ \ \ /__/\ 
    \_\/     \_____\/ \_____\/ \__\/ 
                                 
 all your need infoo!
-->
```

Comment: Your answer is unclear and could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/29986469) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the help center.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Add parent tag (.box) height. 100%, for example